# Multiple Google oath with Laravel Socialite

Tags: php, laravel, google-oauth, laravel-socialite

So right now I have an application that uses Google Authentication in combination with Socialite.  Everything works as expected but what I am trying to do is see if there is a way to allow for multiple domains to login.

Right now I have this under services.php

```
'google' => [
    'client_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => env('GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI'),
],
```

calls

```
    public function redirect(){
    
        return Socialite::driver('google')
            ->scopes(['https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/groups/', \Google_Service_Directory::ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER_READONLY])
            -

>stateless()->redirect();
}
```

wonder if Socialite can take/allow for different

```
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID 
&
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET?
```

Comment: I think you're looking for SSO, Single Sign on, for multiple domains.